# Is there a Sonar, Findbugs, or PMD rule that detects this possible NPE that CodePro detects?

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, pmd, codepro

Let's say I have a block of code like this:

```
Map<String, Object> mappy = 
    (Map<String, Object>)pExtraParameters.get(ServiceClientConstants.EXTRA_PARAMETERS);

if (pSSResponseBean!=null) {
    mappy.put(AddressResearchContext.CSI_RESPONSE_BEAN, (AddressNotFoundResponseBean)pSSResponseBean); // this line may  throw null pointer
}
```

Is there a Sonar, Findbugs, or PMD rule that will flag "mappy" as potentially null?  Apparently CodePro flags this, and I need to provide something similar, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FindBugs treats unannotated items as if they were annotated with `@Nullable` which causes it to ignore nullness checks against them. You can create an empty `java.util` package annotated with a custom `@ReturnValuesAreCheckForNullByDefault` annotation (modify [`@ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault.html)), but it will apply to *every* method in *every* class in that package.

```
@ReturnValuesAreCheckForNullByDefault
package java.util;

import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.ReturnValuesAreCheckForNullByDefault;
```

Another option is to create `Map` facade that has uses the `@CheckForNull` annotation.

```
public class AnnotatedMap<K, E> implements Map<K, E>
{
    private final Map<K, E> wrapped;

    @CheckForNull
    public E get(K key) {
        return wrapped.get(key);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update:** See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206379/285873) to a similar question for complete details on implementing this advice.

Comment: I don't quite get the first technique.  Are you simply saying to define a "java/util/package-info.java" with that annotation in my source tree?  I wonder if that will conflict with an existing "package-info.java" for that package from the JDK?

Comment: I'm also confused about your reference to a "custom" annotation.  I'm guessing you're saying that we should define that annotation, basing it on the existing @ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault annotation, but I have no idea how that new annotation should be different from the existing one.

Comment: Oh, I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194304/how-to-use-findbugs-nonnull-with-external-libraries is relevant to this.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr - Yes, thanks for finding that link. I got interrupted while writing this answer. You understand correctly, except that it doesn't seem to interfere with an existing package info. In the JDK they only contain package comments AFAIK. The new annotation will differ by being annotated with `@CheckForNull` instead of `@Nonnull`. This will apply the former to all method return values in that package.